# Unable to store the results of a double for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, store

I am quite new to R and wrote a double for-loop that does exactly what I want (a block-bootstrap of index numbers with a certain block length). However, I am unable to store in a matrix what print(x_sample) shows me.
I have tried lapply and everything else I could find here, but I was unable to solve the problem by myself. I really hope that you can help.
Many thanks in advance

```
Here is my code:
x <- c(1:1060,1,2,3)
x_sample  <- numeric(119*4)
for (i in 1:3){
    for (j in 0:119){
          idx <- sample(1:1060,1,replace=TRUE)
          x_sample[(4*j+1):(4*j+4)] <- x[(idx):(idx+3)] }
    print(x_sample)}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you the most :)  There will be a checkmark to the left of the answer--click it to accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
values <- c(1:1060, 1, 2, 3)
m <- sapply(sample(1:1060, 360, replace=TRUE), function(idx)values[(idx):(idx+3)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix before the loop, and then fill the matrix:

```
x <- c(1:1060,1,2,3)
mat <- matrix(nrow=480, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 0:119){
    idx <- sample(1:1060,1,replace=TRUE)
    mat[(4*j+1):(4*j+4), i] <- x[(idx):(idx+3)] }
  print(mat)}
```

Comment: thank you EDi! The solution was much easier than I expected. Guess I sill need to practice...